# How to get values in a struct-of-arrays (SOA) through a generic type?

Tags: rust, game-development, entity-component-system

I am looking for your feedback/advice on a piece of code.

Basically, I have a SOA like this one:

```
struct Entities {
    pub meshes: FakeArena<Mesh>,
    pub lights: FakeArena<Light>,
}
```

I can access a particular value through his “handle” (every handle is bound to specific type), so I could get the value of a mesh by doing `entities.meshes.get(&handle)`.

So far, so good, but I’m trying to achieve this by dynamically retrieving the value through the corresponding arena. By doing `entities.get(&handle)` if the handle type is `Mesh`, I return `entities.meshes.get(&handle)`. My `Entities` struct has a method called `get`:

```rust
fn get<T: Any>(&self, handle: &Handle<T>) -> &T {
    let mut entity: Option<&dyn Any> = None;
    let any = handle as &dyn Any;

    any.downcast_ref::<Handle<Mesh>>()
        .map(|handle| entity = Some(self.meshes.get(handle) as &dyn Any));

    any.downcast_ref::<Handle<Light>>()
        .map(|handle| entity = Some(self.lights.get(handle) as &dyn Any));

    if entity.is_none() {
        panic!("Type not found in stored entites.");
    }

    entity
        .unwrap()
        .downcast_ref::<T>()
        .expect("Error while downcasting the entity type")
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=178301a8b93e962801194b550e22fc6b)

This works perfectly. I downcast the generic type into a concrete one, then back again into a generic one, but it seems weird and tricky.

Maybe I'm missing something, or maybe you have a better idea for this; what would you do? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't require any dynamic dispatch here, plain-old static dispatch should be enough.

Create a trait which is given a reference to your container struct. Each component type implements this trait and selects the appropriate field of the container. Then, require the trait in your `get` method and use it:

```
struct Mesh;
struct Light;

struct Entities {
    meshes: Vec<Mesh>,
    lights: Vec<Light>,
}

trait Example {
    fn get_in<'a>(&self, entities: &'a Entities) -> &'a Self;
}

impl Example for Mesh {
    fn get_in<'a>(&self, entities: &'a Entities) -> &'a Self {
        &entities.meshes[0]
    }
}

impl Example for Light {
    fn get_in<'a>(&self, entities: &'a Entities) -> &'a Self {
        &entities.lights[0]
    }
}

impl Entities {
    fn get<T: Example>(&self, handle: T) -> &T {
        handle.get_in(self)
    }
}

fn example(entities: &Entities) {
    let m = entities.get(Mesh);
    let l = entities.get(Light);
}
```

Comment: Oh, It's so much better with your way. Thanks!